# App size on Apple Store

Tags: file, unity-game-engine, size, store

I am using Unity 5.2.0. I developed my game for iOS and android. my android size is 23 MB. I upload and publish my game on apple store, and size is 142 MB for iPhone, 140 MB for iPad, and 43 MB on my macbook iTunes app. What is the reason/problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons. The most significant could be unity's new il2cpp compiler wich generates much bigger builds on ios devices than mono.

There are many threads on the official forums about this topic. Take a look [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html) and [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/il2cpp-build-size-improvements.322079/)

Comment: Yes it is true i used IL2CPP because  i had this issue and i used IL2CPP for solve issue. http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/980007/xcode-error-90086.html   and how can i solve my problem my app folder size is too big in app store. if i use mono2x i have error

Comment: You wont be able to use mono anymore because it doesnt support 64bit builds. Just take a look at the links i posted, there ware a few ways to reduce the build size. e.g. usw .net 2 subset instead of .Net 2, ...